# Opencv change colors in specified threshold

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have 16bit grayscale png images. I want to emphasize some part of the image with changing specific pixel colors to red or maybe to white.

The part i want to emphasize has different gray levels from the rest of picture. So I tried to changing color with thresholding like:

```
Mat img = cv::imread("/file/path/x.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

img2 = img;
int low=100, high=150;
    for(int j=0;j<img2.rows;j++)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<img2.cols;i++)
        {
            int pixelVal = (int)img2.at<uchar>(j,i);
            if(pixelVal >= low && pixelVal <= high){
                img2.at<uchar>(j,i) = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

But I have 2 problems here, `cerr << (int)img2.at<uchar>(j,i)` prints value inside `0-255` so it looks i couldnt read image as 16bit, its 8 bit. I tried several flags for `imread` but still same. So how can read it as 16bit?

Secondly, are there any better way to do it instead changing colors pixel by pixel with loop? Some function maybe?

I use Linux and Opencv 3.4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are specifying the type as `at<uchar>` , so pixel values are read **as** `uchar` (regardless of the actual format).
  If you want to access to pixel values as 16bit type, you must specify the 16bit type to the template parameter.
- To load 16bit image, try to use other `cv::ImreadModes` flags.
  ( maybe `IMREAD_UNCHANED` or `IMREAD_ANYDEPTH` ? )
  And, to confirm the load result, check the value returned from `cv::Mat::depth()`.

> Secondly, are there any better way to do it instead changing colors pixel by pixel with loop? Some function maybe?

Using some methods/functions will be conceivable. e.g. `inRange()` and then `Mat::setTo()`.
But, I think straightforward way is with loop.

Comment: Thanks for answer, now i can see values up to 65k with ```uint16_t```. But I have some other problems now. I fixed one error in code to ```img2=img.clone()``` because it was changing original image too. But color transformation just applied to left half of the image.

Comment: Sorry i fixed it. Any idea for changing it to red?

Comment: You say "change", but "grayscale" image can not represent "color".
So, what to do will depend on what is your desired result.
e.g. If you want to "display (visualize) the places where the pixel values are in a specific range in red", simply render the value range check result on other format(can represent color) image and show it.

Comment: For example, to visualize, create a 8bit-3ch image (BGR image, has same size).
And then decide all pixel value of this color image buffer based on your source 16bit image's pixel value. (finally, show or save it.)